# MagicalRecord's MR_InContext method. Safe to use?

Tags: swift, core-data, magicalrecord

I was wondering if it was safe to call MR_InContext in conjunction with saveWithBlock. I know apple suggests not even READING from core data objects in a different thread, so I'm wondering if I should be passing the objectId instead. Here is an example of what I'm talking about:

```
// outside of save with block
var someManagedObject = SomeManagedObject.MR_first()

MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({ (localContext : NSManagedObjectContext!) in

        // Is this ok? should I pass the objectId instead?
        var managedObjectInThread = someManagedObject.MR_InContext(localContext)
        managedObjectInThread.date = NSDate()

}, completion: { (success : Bool, error : NSError!) in
       // This block runs in main thread
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. This is the type of scenario for which this method was intended.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [GDCoreDataConcurrencyDebugging](https://github.com/GrahamDennis/GDCoreDataConcurrencyDebugging) framework:

Invalid concurrent access to managed object (Question) calling 'release' when I used `MR_InContext`

Instead of I had to keep a reference to the `objectID` and use it inside the block.